# How to encode the js code only using l and I

Tags: javascript, encode

Recently, I found a chrome extension [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko). I want to study the js code of this extension. But the variables in the css and js file constructed only by `l` and `I`. The code is unreadable.

So  I Google to find some tools change the js code unreadable. but failed.

- I want to know Which tools can do this.
- and I want to know if there is a tools can guess the origin file (some popular js library)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was most likely minified (which decreases the file size, as well as makes it unreadable). You can use this site to minify your code: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/
You can check the **Base62 Encode** option to obfuscate the code further.

In order to make minified code more readable, use a Javascript beautifier: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: if there is a tools can guess the origin file (at leaset for  some popular js library, we may guess it)?

Comment: Unless the author of the plugin releases the source, using JS Beautifier is the closest you're going to get to the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Many developers want to protect their work and use "code obfuscators" to make the code unreadable.

Google for "javascript deobfuscate" to get a list of tools that can revert (some) of the damage. [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) is one of them.